# TypeError: records.map is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dictionary

I am getting this error 'TypeError: records.map is not a function' when I am trying to map data into a table from props. Please help me

data looks like this when I console.log it

```
(82) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/87cb30d8-80df-11ea-8951-00000000092a.png", ticker: "AAPL", name: "Apple Inc", marketCapitalization: 2068723}
1: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: null, ticker: "ALJJ", name: "ALJ Regional Holdings Inc", marketCapitalization: 41}
2: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/9564945e-80df-11ea-9144-00000000092a.png", ticker: "ALLT", name: "Allot Ltd", marketCapitalization: 0}
3: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/95ff91b4-80df-11ea-a942-00000000092a.png", ticker: "ALOT", name: "AstroNova Inc", marketCapitalization: 50}
4: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: null, ticker: "ALRM", name: "Alarm.com Holdings Inc", marketCapitalization: 2874}
5: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: null, ticker: "ALTR", name: "Altair Engineering Inc", marketCapitalization: 2919}
6: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/af289222-80da-11ea-a616-00000000092a.png", ticker: "ALYA.TO", name: "Alithya Group Inc", marketCapitalization: 132}
7: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/a393333e-80df-11ea-819f-00000000092a.png", ticker: "ASUR", name: "Asure Software Inc", marketCapitalization: 109}
8: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: null, ticker: "ATEN", name: "A10 Networks Inc", marketCapitalization: 572}
9: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/b9784a8c-80df-11ea-9db3-00000000092a.png", ticker: "BSQR", name: "Bsquare Corp", marketCapitalization: 19}
10: {finnhubIndustry: "Technology", logo: "https://static.finnhub.io/logo/bbbad626-80d4-11ea-a7d3-00000000092a.png", ticker: "COUP", name: "Coupa Software Inc", marketCapitalization: 19170}
```

This is passed to industryTable.js as props

industryTable.js

```
const IndustryTable = ({ ticker, relatedTicker }) => { //relatedTicker passed in as props
    const records = [relatedTicker]; 
    console.log(relatedTicker); //see console.log above

...title and other jsx...

                    <tbody>
                        {records.map((record, index) => { //const. map over each column I needed
                            return (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{record.ticker}</td>
                                    <td>{record.name}</td>
                                    <td>{record.marketCapitalization}</td>
                                    <td>{record.finnhubIndustry}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. If `[relatedTicker]` is the array you've `console.log`ed, then what's `relatedTicker`?

Comment: I console.logged relatedTicker not [relatedTicker]. I added the brackets to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Sorry - I meant that if you're iterating `[relatedTicker]` then it contains a single element, which is the array `relatedTicker`

Comment: I changed it to iterate just `relatedTicker ` and I get the `TypeError: records.map is not a function`. I got the data from a rest api call and tried to pass it as props to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in the case of the variable records beeing null, your render function still tries to access the map function of your records variable, which of course ends with the 'TypeError: records.map is not a function' error.

You have to check if records is null and only map it's data if it is not null. You can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to do it like this:

```
{records && records.map((record, index) = ....}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for taking the time to look at this for me!!

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to set the array of your data to the state, then pass array from state to the child componenet and use it whith props